# Chrome not reachable

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium

I am getting the below error message when running my unit tests. Can anyone tell me what is causing this and how to resolve?

> Error:
> chrome not reachable
>
> (Driver info: > chromedriver=0.7,platform=Windows NT 6.1 x86) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>
> Command duration or timeout: 21.58 seconds

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=214

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=308

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=321

Comment: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/938

Comment: Well, I mean, we need more details. If the above is of no help, please tell us what Chrome version you are using, what version of the Chrome Driver you are using, and what version of Selenium are you using? Also, did they work before and suddenly stop? Indicative of a silent Chrome upgrade if this is the case.