# Selenium Chrome DevTools: Unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at localhost:6666 from chrome not reachable

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to execute my selenium automation in a chrome which is already open.

I follow these steps: https://medium.com/@harith.sankalpa/connect-selenium-driver-to-an-existing-chrome-browser-instance-41435b67affd

I open a chrome with this line:

```
/opt/google/chrome/chrome --remote-debugging-port=6666
```

This is my java code

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/../chromedriver");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("debuggerAddress","localhost:6666");
// Initialize browser
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
// Open Google
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
WebElement searchBox = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
searchBox.sendKeys("jrichardsz");    
// Close browser
driver.close();
```

When I run this code I get this log:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 84.0.4147.30 (48b3e868c0aa7e814951969b4c0b6f6949e110a8-refs/branch-heads/4147@{#310}) on port 12155
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
```

And after some seconds  I get: **chrome not reachable** error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at localhost:6666
from chrome not reachable
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'jane_doe', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '***', java.version: '1.8.0_151'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
remote stacktrace: #0 0x556168a87ea9 <unknown>

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:498)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:464)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:74)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:157)
    at OpenedChrome.main(OpenedChrome.java:24)
```

I tried also with chromiun and opera and I get the same error.

My chrome is opened but java cannot connect to it.

I reviewed these links unlucky

- [Headless chrome: chrome not reachable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45170002/headless-chrome-chrome-not-reachable)
- [WebDriverException: chrome not reachable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30978504/webdriverexception-chrome-not-reachable)
- [Chrome not reachable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16178753/chrome-not-reachable)

Answer (score 1):

You can set below property to check the debug logs

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.verboseLogging", "true");
```

**Example for Windows OS:**

If any existing chrome process is running and you have open new instance of chrome using

```
> chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222
```

then you may get below logs while executing the selenium script in question

```
[DEBUG]: DevTools HTTP Request: http://localhost:9222/json/version
[DEBUG]: DevTools HTTP Request failed
```

To open the clean instance of chrome browser for debugging

> chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222 --no-first-run --no-default-browser-check --user-data-dir="D:\remotedebugfolder"

Now run the selenium with

```
options.setExperimentalOption("debuggerAddress","localhost:9222");
```

Comment: Thanks for your tips. I will research if another process are using the same port

Comment: Hi @JRichardsz, Even I'm facing same problem can you plz help me resolving this? if you were unblocked. Thanks in Advance. I get below exception- WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at localhost:9222

Comment: Hi @satya, I anwser my own question with the steps that I followed to fix this error. I hope this helps you. Try to contact me if your error continues.

Comment: chrome verboselogging helped me... thanks

Answer (score 1):

On my case this was due because I was using a port (6666) to start my chrome in debug mode, which is restricted according to : **restricted [Unsafe] ports list on Chrome**

```
6665,    // Alternate IRC [Apple addition]
6666,    // Alternate IRC [Apple addition]
6667,    // Standard IRC [Apple addition]
```

A complete chrome list is [here](https://superuser.com/a/188070/881022) and [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/refs/heads/main/net/base/port_util.cc). Firefox allowed ports [here](https://www-archive.mozilla.org/projects/netlib/portbanning#portlist). Also how to force to allow some ports, [here](https://superuser.com/questions/188006/how-to-fix-err-unsafe-port-error-on-chrome-when-browsing-to-unsafe-ports)

#### Steps to identify the error

- If I startup my chrome in debug mode at port **wxyz**. I need to validate if this port is correctly used by chrome or just if this port is listening.
- Port listening could be validated using `telnet localhost wxyz` or in windows with `nc -zvv localhost wxyz`
- I found another option to validate if chrome has started successfully using this port. It was a kind of http like `http://localhost:wxyz/json/version`. If port is listening, a json response is received. If due to some issue like not allowed ports, chrome is not picking this port, `http://localhost:wxyz/json/version` returns an error. If I found the real endpoint I will update this answer.

If port is listening correctly, another low level error is the reason:

- Just check your java code to point to exact port.
- Driver exact version. Selenium is very sensitive to the drivers version.
- Used browser version compatible with driver version.
- Try on linux. In windows some unexpected errors appear.